Does Lavinia, Azorius Renegade work against Kinnan, Bonder Prodigy?
Do either of Lavinia, Azorius Renegade's abilities:

Each opponent can’t cast noncreature spells with mana value greater than the number of lands that player controls.
Whenever an opponent casts a spell, if no mana was spent to cast it, counter that spell.

work against Kinnan, Bonder Prodigy's second ability:

{5}{G}{U}: Look at the top five cards of your library. You may put a non-Human creature card from among them onto the battlefield. Put the rest on the bottom of your library in a random order.

Basically, does Kinnan's ability count as "casting"? Would Lavinia counter that spell - or not because it's not being cast?

No, casting a spell is a specific action, defined by Comprehensive Rule 601.2:

601.2 To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect.

Kinnan's ability simply puts a creature onto the battlefield; it is not casting a spell, therefore neither of Lavinia's abilities apply. Abilities which mean you cast the spell make this clear, for example Aetherworks Marvel:

{T}, Pay six {E}: Look at the top six cards of your library. You may cast a spell from among them without paying its mana cost. Put the rest on the bottom of your library in a random order.

which would cause the spell to be countered by Lavinia's second ability as you are paying no mana for it.

Aetherworks Marvel is a good example of a similar card that does cast the card you get

No. A creature card is a creature when on the battlefield, a spell when on the stack, and just a card everywhere else. Kinnan moves the card directly from your deck onto the battlefield, without going onto the stack in between, so it's never a spell, let alone a spell that was cast. Also, you can counter something only while it's on the stack. Since the card is never on the stack, Lavini's second ability can't counter it. If you have something like Stifle, you can counter Kinnan's ability, but once the ability starts to resolve, no one gets priority until the card is already on the battlefield.
